# Excluding the IDFA from the final binary using Countly

Tags: ios, objective-c, c-preprocessor, countly-analytics

I'm trying to exclude the IDFA from my final binary using Countly so I can answer no to the Export Compliance question "Does your app use the IDFA?".

Adding `COUNTLY_EXCLUDE_IDFA=1` to `Build Settings > Preprocessor Macros` as mentioned [here](https://resources.count.ly/docs/countly-sdk-for-ios-and-os-x#section-app-store-connect-idfa-warning) doesn't work.

I've narrowed it down to `#ifndef` not behaving as expected. This is what I've tried:

With `COUNTLY_EXCLUDE_IDFA=1` added in `Build Settings > Preprocessor Macros`:

```
#ifndef COUNTLY_EXCLUDE_IDFA
    printf("!EXCLUDED\n");
#else
    printf("EXCLUDED\n");
#endif

>> prints !EXCLUDED
```

With `COUNTLY_EXCLUDE_IDFA` not defined in `Build Settings > Preprocessor Macros`:

```
#ifndef COUNTLY_EXCLUDE_IDFA
    printf("!EXCLUDED\n");
#else
    printf("EXCLUDED\n");
#endif

>> prints !EXCLUDED
```

I expect `#ifndef` to include a block if the Macro is not defined. Now the `#ifndef` block is included wether or not I have the Macro defined in `Build Settings > Preprocessor Macros`.

Comment: When you set this macro in your `Preprocessor Macros`, I presume you're setting it under release builds only, right? In that case, are these tests you show coming from a release build, or a debug build?

Comment: I've set the ```Preprocessor Macros``` for all build configurations, so that the IDFA is never included. I've tested this in a debug build. When I upload a release binary to AppStoreConnect I get a warning that the IDFA is included in the binary as well.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you set `COUNTLY_EXCLUDE_IDFA` for the correct target and build configuration.

If you are adding Countly iOS SDK source files directly to your project, make sure the flag is added to your app target.

If you are adding it as a framework, make sure the flag is added to framework target.

Answer (score 0):

I have this in `Podfile`, and it works fine.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == "Countly"
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)', 'COUNTLY_EXCLUDE_IDFA=1']
      end
    end
  end
end
```